# Write the contents of node debug log to file

Tags: node.js, bash, pipe, stdout

I can I write the contents of this output to a file? I'm using the [debug](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) module to log messages, I'd like to be able to pipe them to a file. However its not working as expected.

```
$ DEBUG=* node -e 'var debug = require("debug")("test"); debug("hello world")'
    test hello world +0ms
$ DEBUG=* node -e 'var debug = require("debug")("test"); debug("hello world")' > temp.txt
    test hello world +0ms
```

Just tried this and received no output as well.

```
$ { DEBUG=* node -e "var debug = require('debug')('test'); debug('hello world')"; } >temp.txt
    test hello world +0ms
```

Comment: I've stuck with the same problem with only one difference. If I'm running my application with node - everything is cool and debug works, but if I runnig my application with nodemon - I receive exactly the same error.

I have created small demo repo https://github.com/speedster-kiev/debug-nodemon-error that shows the error.

Any advises?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure you running the latest version of `debug`.
2. You need to use the `DEBUG_FD=3` env flag as well as `3>` to pipe

Here's an example.

```
$ DEBUG_FD=3 DEBUG=foo node -e "require('debug')('foo')('hello')" 3> foo.txt
```

From the repo's issue [request/question: is there a way for debug to log to a file?](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/192)

Answer (score 3):

Using the `DEBUG_FD=3` did not work for me.

The option that worked for me is using the `2>` to the pipe:

```
DEBUG=* node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 . 2> log.txt
```